# Specify multiple JNDI Connection URL's in weblogic

Tags: jms, weblogic, weblogic12c, tibco

In Weblogic you can specify multiple JNDI Connection URL's split by a ',' under JMS Modules.

JNDI Connection URL for example

```
tibjmsnaming://serverName1:12,tibjmsnaming://serverName2:12
```

You can also specify it with TCP for example

```
tcp://serverName1:12,tcp://serverName2:12
```

I tried looking for this on the net but it is unclear from [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html) documentation and sites.

What I want to know is:

1. If you specify more than 1 server like above what server will be tried first? Will it always connect to server1 if server1 is always available. Or will it randomly choose one?
2. What is the difference in using `tibjmsnaming` and `tcp`? Looking at the `tibjmsnaming` - in the logs it still says connected to `tcp:serverName1:12`. Which makes it a bit confusing as to what `tibjmsnaming` really does.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my findings no matter which way you specify it in the Weblogic console aka `tibjmsnaming` and `tcp`it will use an underlying `tcp` connection. It will also use the first available one from left to right.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering your own question. This solved a question for me today that was not obvious. You're a credit to technologists everywhere.